# Match values between columns in different dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have two dataframes containing ";" separated IDs. I want to see which IDs in df2$Protein.IDs are in df1$subunits.UniProt.IDs., and ideally return the matching IDs as a list.
I'm not sure how to approach this as I haven't come across anything in previous questions.
I'm trying to use strsplit separate the IDs for each entry, then search for matches for each one, with the goal of iterating across the df by a for loop, but I'm a bit stuck on how to make it come together.

```
df1 <- structure(list(ComplexName = c("Oligosaccharyltransferase complex (Stt3B variant)", 
"TRF1-TIN2 complex", "TRF1 telomere length regulation complex", 
"Rap1 complex", "TRF2-Rap1 complex III", "TRF-Rap1 complex I, 2MD"
), Organism = c("Mouse", "Mouse", "Mouse", "Mouse", "Mouse", 
"Mouse"), subunits.UniProt.IDs. = c("Q91YQ5;Q9DBG6;O54734;P61804;Q8BTV1;Q3TDQ1;Q9CQY5", 
"P70371;Q5EE38;Q9QXG9;Q91WC1", "Q6PFX9;P70371;Q9QXG9", "P70371;O35144;P70388;Q5EE38;Q9QXG9;Q91WC1;Q91VL8", 
"O35144;Q91VL8", "Q6PFX9;P70371;O35144;Q9QXG9;Q91WC1;Q91VL8")), row.names = 881:886, class = "data.frame")
```

```
df2 <- structure(list(Protein.IDs = c("E9QN37;A1L314", "A2A6U3;Q80UG5-2;Q80UG5-3;Q80UG5;A2A6U5;A8Y5D3", 
"A2A7A7;Q8CFX1;A2A7A8", "A6PW84;A2A7Q5;Q3V1T4-3;Q3V1T4", "A2ACG7;Q9DBG6", 
"F6TBV1;F6WHL0;A2ADH1;Q9CQY5-2;Q9CQY5-3;Q9CQY5", "A2AEM2;Q99LI2", 
"A2AFS0;Q8C483;P26638;A2AFS1", "A2AFW6;Q9D050;Q791V5;D6RCZ1", 
"Q3UB58;Q3UNJ0;A2AIN5;Q3UZ35;P21855", "A2AIW9;Q9DC61", "A2AL36;E9Q9E7;A2AS42;F6QP53;A2AL36-2", 
"A2AL50;Q8C0I1;H3BKN2;A2AL49;H3BIY5", "Q8CBM2;A2AL85;Q8BSY0", 
"A2AMH3;A2AMH5;A2AMH4;Q6X893;Q6X893-2;A2AMH8", "A2AMW0;P47757-2;A2AMV7;P47757;F6QJN8;F6YHZ8;F7CAZ6", 
"Q3U8S1;A2APM5;A2APM3;A2APM4;E9QKM8;Q80X37;A2APM1;A2APM2;P15379-2;P15379-3;P15379-6;P15379-11;P15379-5;P15379-10;P15379-9;P15379-4;P15379-8;P15379-7;P15379;P15379-12;P15379-13", 
"A2AR26;Q3UDF0;A2AR27", "E9Q8N1;E9Q8K5;A2ASS6;A2ASS6-2;A2AT70;F7CR78", 
"A2AUR7;Q9D031;Q01730"), Gene.names = c("Mpeg1", "Sep-09", "H6pd", 
"P3h1;Lepre1", "Rpn2", "Magt1", "Clcc1", "Sars", "Mtch2", "Cd72", 
"Pmpca", "Cntrl", "Agps", "Asph", "Slc44a1", "Capzb", "Cd44", 
"Slc2a6", "Ttn", "Rsu1")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming, the column is added in 'df2', we can use `strsplit` from `base R` to split both the relevant columns in the datasets, use `intersect` to find the common elements in each element of the `list`

```
un1 <- unique(unlist(strsplit(df1$subunits.UniProt.IDs., ";")))
df2$Common <- lapply(strsplit(df2$Protein.IDs, ";"), intersect, un1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `stringr` (or simply `tidyverse`):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df2 %>% 
  mutate(Protein = str_split(Protein.IDs, ";")) %>% 
  unnest(Protein) %>% 
  inner_join(df1 %>% 
              mutate(Protein = str_split(subunits.UniProt.IDs., ";")) %>% 
              unnest(Protein), by="Protein")
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  Protein.IDs                Gene.names Protein ComplexName                Organism subunits.UniProt.IDs.        
  <chr>                      <chr>      <chr>   <chr>                      <chr>    <chr>                        
1 A2ACG7;Q9DBG6              Rpn2       Q9DBG6  Oligosaccharyltransferase~ Mouse    Q91YQ5;Q9DBG6;O54734;P61804;~
2 F6TBV1;F6WHL0;A2ADH1;Q9CQ~ Magt1      Q9CQY5  Oligosaccharyltransferase~ Mouse    Q91YQ5;Q9DBG6;O54734;P61804;~
```

We splitted the `Protein.IDs` / `subunits.UniProt.IDs.` at `;` and inner joined both tables by the resulting column.

Since both transformations for `df1` and `df2` are basically the same, you can wrap it into a function. This is useful, if you have to process several more data.frames:

```r
split_function <- function(df, column, new_col) {
  df %>% 
    mutate({{new_col}} := str_split({{column}}, ";")) %>% 
    unnest({{new_col}})
}

inner_join(split_function(df1, subunits.UniProt.IDs., Protein), 
           split_function(df2, Protein.IDs, Protein),
           by = "Protein")
```